# Problem converting fixed points to float in python

Tags: python, numpy, hex, fixed-point

I'm reading a minew beacon using python numpy and now i'm having problems to convert the fixed points to float.

On the Minew E7 datasheet I have the following information: 
[Datasheet infos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIdL2.png)

I have to convert a fixed point 8.8 to a float.

I'm using the following code to convert:

```py
from rig.type_casts import fp_to_float

def convertFixedPToFloat(hexaString):
   hexaInt16 = int(hexaString,16)
   f4 = fp_to_float(n_frac=8)
   return (f4(hexaInt16))
```

If you look in to the datasheet, the hex number 0xFFFE has to be -0.01, but what my function is returning is: 255.9921875

my phython version is Python 3.7.3

How can i convert it on the rigth way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the unsigned integer into signed.

```
if hexaInt16 >= 0x8000:
    hexaInt16 -= 0x10000
```

The above is specific to the numbers in your question.  For a more general purpose unsigned to signed conversion you can use this function.

```
def signed(n, bits=16):
    n &= (1 << bits) - 1
    if n >> (bits - 1):
        n -= 1 << bits
    return n
```